# React-Native: Limit the length of Text displayed in a Card Section

Tags: react-native

I have a large Text field and when i am displaying it in a card section i need to trim it at the end and show only up to a particular length.

For example:
If the text is:

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
> industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
> since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
> scrambled it to mak

I need to cut the length to get a text like:

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text...

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can combine `numberOfLines` and `width / flex` prop to achieve this effect.

```
<Text numberOfLines={1} style={{ width: 100 }}>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
    typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
    printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to mak
</Text>
```

Comment: In case, it still doesn't provide the required result, then make sure your text node styles have the {flex:1}.

Answer (score 40):

please check this code. you adjust text length according to your space

```
 <Text numberOfLines={1}>
              {address.length < 35
                ? `${address}`
                : `${address.substring(0, 32)}...`}
            </Text>
```

Answer (score 6):

### 2022 answer

---

Simply do the following 2 steps.

1. Set **numberOfLines** prop to a number greater than 0 and
2. Now you can use the **ellipsizeMode** prop to control how the text is truncated. here tail means after the 2nd line reached it will add dots like this "some text..." check the [official docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#ellipsizemode) to know about this more

```js
<Text numberOfLines={2} ellipsizeMode="tail">
 lorem ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
</Text>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `style={{flex: 1}}` in card or text styling to limit within the card. Use `numberOfLines={1}` to restrict in one line.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Text numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode="tail">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
    typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
    printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to mak
</Text>
```

Comment: ellipsizeMode="tail" is not working in react native .